#  ob_start(), ob_get_contents()  do not work in preprocess functions?

Tags: theming

I tried to catch some HTML output in preprocess function with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()`, but the output seems to slip through them. Is **output_buffering** maybe disabled in Drupal?

This is the pseudo code from `mytheme_preprocess_page()`:

```
ob_start(); ?>
<div id="block">
    <span>This is block</span>
</div>
<?php $vars['my_block'] = ob_get_contents();
```

When I do this, I get the `<div>` output directly and not dumped to `$vars['my_block']`, as one would expect. My guess is that output buffering is, for some reasons, disabled. I am wondering if that is the case and why.

Comment: You should show your actual code; clearly, you would not use such code, in your module.

Comment: Drupal 6 uses `ob_get_contents()`, and it works.

Comment: Having HTML in PHP functions is discouraged, I think that includes preprocess functions as well (not theme functions, obviously). I really suggest you either create a theme function or use render arrays to create your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think nothing is left on buffer in Drupal. After evaluating each template the rendered output is preserved as value and passed to outer level template. In this scheme Drupal might be getting buffered content and clearing it across each template.

That is why you should look for variables in that scope.

Comment: I've clarified my question, I think it was confusing.